# Ghost & Wordpress One Droplet

Tags: wordpress, nginx, ghost

I have 3 Wordpress sites (2 clients one mine)
I have them in a droplet on Digital Ocean.

I have 1 Ghost website on a different droplet

I am considering moving the wordpress sites to the ghost droplet so I can **consolidate everything to one server** I am moving the wordpress sites to the ghost server.

**I was following this link** -
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-virtual-hosts-server-blocks-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts--3

**Then a user told me I have to do this as well** -
nginx fastcgi php

The entire process seems disjointed in the end I found this code on stack overflow for a NGINX config now I don't know where to begin. Where should I start?

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name wordpress-blog-doamin.com;

    location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

#

```
server {                                                                         
listen 80;                                                             
server_name ghost-blog-domain.com ;                                      

client_max_body_size 10M;

location / {                                                             
        proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/;                               
        proxy_set_header Host $host;                                     
        proxy_buffering off;                                             
}                                                                        
}
```